# Hide and show div when page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a div :

```
<div id="postreply">
    <asp:Label ID="lbStatus" CssClass="input-large1" runat="server" Text="Close" Width="600px"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

i try to hide div when page load :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {            
        var x = document.getElementById('lbStatus').innerText;
        if(x == "Close"){
            $("#postreply").hide();
        }
    }</script>
```

anyone help me hide this div with lbStatus.Text = Close

Comment: is it not enought to make `document.getElementById('postreply').style.display = 'none';` ? Then it's not visible and you can change it back when you need.

Comment: Hide in css first, then show it when finished loading?

Comment: @elclanrs - if (s)he's having trouble hiding it, how will (s)he show it? ;)

Comment: i want to hide div with lbstatus.Text = close but i can't hide div

Comment: can't u set `ClientIdMode = Static` for your label  and check the same code.

Comment: Why are you using Javascript AND jQyery methods? Why not just `var x = $('#lbStatus').text()` instead of `var x = document.getElementById('lbStatus').innerText;`

Comment: i change document.getElementById('postreply').style.display = 'none'; but this still happen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, once with `$(document).ready`, it executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready where as `window.onload` executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($("#lbStatus").val() == "Close"){
        $("#postreply").hide();
    }
});
```

As you are using `Asp.Net` try to use `ClientId` property

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($("#<%=lbStatus.ClientID%>").val() == "Close"){
        $("#postreply").hide();
    }
});
```

Changed `<%=lbStatus.ClientID%>` instead of `lbStatus`

Reference: http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/

Comment: i can't get $("#lbStatus").val() i try to alert lbstatus but not thing display

Answer (score 6):

Can't you simply use CSS for this?

```
#postreply {
   display: none; /* onLoad your div will be hidden */
}
```

Comment: Maybe your answer was just too intimidating for the competition.  I'll get you back in there, it's a good answer.

Comment: @Steve Well thanks, but I've provided a solution that works, I don't know why others down vote without providing any reason, if they prove my answer wrong, I'll delete them right away :)

Comment: Yeah that irritates me too.  After a second look at the code one notices that it's in the `window.load` method, so CSS is the correct answer IMO, and you were first.

Comment: @Steve Yea exactly, I wouldn't have answered if this was not on load, also if we hide things with js on load, and the browsers js is turned off, it will harm the layout, but when it's CSS, there's no way it will spoil your layout as the element will be hidden on load

Answer (score 2):

You mix up between pure javascript and jQuery.
If you not include jquery library, use pure javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {            
    var x = document.getElementById('lbStatus').innerText;
    if(x == "Close"){
      // $("#postreply").hide();
      document.getElementById('postreply').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I dont sure about asp tag work, Can you show generated html from that tag ?

Answer (score 1):

<s>Looks like you need to remove the `#` sign.</s>

<s>$('postreply').hide();</s>

Or, vanilla Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('postreply').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Steve, should an id not have `#` in jQuery?

Comment: Oops...I never use JQuery :)

Comment: Yea even this works well, I don't know why it wasn't up voted as well, +1 to you too..

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it from the start.

Either with **javascript**: `document.getElementById('lbStatus').style.display = 'none';` and to get it back "visible" use `document.getElementById('lbStatus').style.display = "";`

or with **css**: `#lbStatus{display: none;}`